# How to execute a loop with multiple arguments in Google Chrome inspect element console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I was wondering where I went wrong and how I can utilize the console found within the inspect element function of chrome? I wrote this code for the Inspect Element Console to try and speed up a repetitive task in google chrome.

```
    int RED = 0;
    loop 
    {
        RED++; 
        (function(){jQuery('.btn_grey_black').map(function()  {this.click()})})();                
        Navigated to http://steamcommunity.com/id/hellowhatsupidk/myworkshopfiles/?browsesort=mysubscriptions&browsefilter=mysubscriptions&p = RED;
    }
```

It was meant to:

1. Declare an int RED and set it to 0.
2. Start a infinite loop that would:

   1. increment RED.
   2. execute a click function.
   3. navigate to a certain page where the page URL utilized the value of  RED.

//As is very clear I am not familiar with JavaScript or the developer console. Please excuse my ignorance.

Comment: Your problem is that you don't actually know javascript. You need to read a few tutorials or something.

Comment: Okay i will keep doing that then. I figured my Java might work in the Java script console but it seems they are very different in syntax. Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah, for a start there is no strict typing in javascript, so your `int` should be `var`. And loops are done with the `while` keyword

Comment: Thank you! You have been a huge help just one more thing, What command can I use in the console to navigate to a URL?

Comment: `window.location = "http://google.com"` will redirect the current window/tab, `window.open("http://google.com")` should open a new one.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `shift + enter` to type multi line commands.

Another way is to write the code in an editor, copy it, and paste it in the chrome console.